# Test for Exactness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

[image]

In this theorem apperas:"(simply conected)" i don't understand why.
Because we can proof with out use "(simply connected)":
if we assume that: exist $\phi(x,y) $ s.t $\phi_{x}=\frac{ \partial\phi}{\partial x}=M$ and $\phi_{y}=\frac{ \partial\phi}{\partial y}=N$ then $\phi_{xy}=M_y$ and $\phi_{yx}=N_x $ but from continuity of $M_y$ and $N_x $ and symmetry of second derivatives (schwarz theorem) it follows $\phi_{xy}=\phi_{yx}$ and (1.9.5) is proven.
To proof converse is just an algorithm to find $\phi$ using integration and (1.9.5)

Where we need simply connected?

Comment: The standard example is the angle of the point $x,y$, the gradient makes a nice exact vector field outside the origin, but going once around the origin will increase the angle by $2\pi$.

Comment: In not sure this is correct, but I think it is: The simply-connected requirement (along with the others) is a sufficient condition. It's not the weakest sufficient condition, but it is sufficient to guarantee that you can write down a potential function $\phi$. This is like if I said that running 10,000 miles is sufficient to burn 1 calorie. However running 10,000 miles is not the weakest sufficient condition. I'm in the process of collecting my thoughts for an answer but I'm not sure if I know this subject well enough to give an answer

Comment: Whether the 2-dimensional domain is simply-connected or not simply-connected, you just need every point of your integration rectangle, to be a point of the domain. Then you can define a potential function over that integration rectangle, a subset of the full domain. I hope someone else comes along and answers the question. I would leave an answer but now I'm getting confused. In 2-dimensions, simply-connected is easy to understand. Given a point $(x_0, y_0)$ contained in the common domain, it seems like you can always find the other 3 vertices of an integration rectangle, whose area is in $D$